# Dynamicly create unicode variable from string

Tags: javascript, unicode

I have around 3000 html elements each representing a certain browser emoji. The elements contain a CSS class representing the emoji's unicode:

```
<span class="_1f603"></span>
<span class="_1f604"></span>
```

I want to convert the unicode to its representing short code:

```
\u{1f603} = ':grinning:'
```

I already have a working function for that part. The problem is building up the correct unicode string using the class name (as I don't intend to do all 3000 elements manually).

To get what I want I've written the following code:

```
function setShortCode(ele){
    let classArray = ele.className.split(' ');

    for(let i=0; i<classArray.length; i++){
        if(classArray[i].startsWith('_')){
            htmlUnicodeString = classArray[i].substr(1);
            jsUnicodeString = '\u{'+htmlUnicodeString+'}';

            document.getElementById('chat-text').value = document.getElementById('chat-text').value + joypixels.toShort(jsUnicodeString);
        }
    }
}
```

It returns this error:

> SyntaxError: malformed Unicode character escape sequence

Appearently it's not allowed to dynamicly create unicode strings in this way?

Comment: `String.fromCodePoint`

Comment: @DanielA.White Amazing! Thanks a lot, that worked like a charm! Feel free to turn it into an answer if you want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `String.fromCodePoint`